# Adhoc build is crashing not debug build

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode4.5

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xa151830c
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x3b766b26 objc_msgSend + 6
1   Foundation                      0x31e31386 __NSFireDelayedPerform + 410
2   CoreFoundation                  0x314220dc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
3   CoreFoundation                  0x31421cf2 __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 778
4   CoreFoundation                  0x3142008e __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
5   CoreFoundation                  0x3138ac22 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3138aa06 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
7   GraphicsServices                0x3607a27e GSEventRunModal + 134
8   UIKit                           0x33c2e044 UIApplicationMain + 1132
9   deBodas                         0x000d5c6e main (main.m:16)
10  deBodas                         0x000c53fc ___lldb_unnamed_function1$$deBodas + 36


This is crash log when i install the build .It is happend when install the build adhoc not a debug build
```

When i install build through system it is not happend.Any body knows please help me

I am struck this issue last three days.

Comment: How you are installing your ad hoc build?

Comment: After archiving upload in test flight

Comment: Do you have any NSTimer scheduled that you are not invalidating after some screen was disappeared?

Comment: it is global object in appdelegate

Comment: Maybe some method is not declared? Refer to last line `lldb_unnamed_function1$$deBodas`